# Using regex and clean string memory?

Tags: c#, regex

I have a simple code in regex:

```
string strFile5 = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\dennis\Desktop\regex.txt"); 

strFile5 = Regex.Replace(strFile5, @"Documents", "document2");
File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\dennis\Desktop\regex2.txt", strFile5);
```

I want to remove strFile5 from memory.

Comment: Um..Set to null? Its pretty hard to do since strings are immutable. What are your concerns?

Comment: why are you using the `Regex` library at all

Comment: 1) regex in that problem is overkill, 2) you don't need to worry about it, GC will do all work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The GC marks local variables for collection when they are not used anymore. So you don't need to worry about that your self.

Read : [Should I Set Variables to Null to Assist Garbage Collection](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2010/02/q-should-i-set-variables-to-null-to.html) ?

Example by Jeffrey Richter in CLR via C#:

```
public static void Main() 
{  
    Timer t = new Timer(TimerCallback, null, 0, 2000);           
    Console.ReadLine();     
}
```

> When the collection starts, it first assumes that all objects in the
>   heap are unreachable (garbage); this includes the Timer object. Then,
>   the collector examines the application’s roots and sees that Main
>   **doesn’t use the t variable** after the initial assignment to it.
>   Therefore, the application has no variable referring to the Timer
>   object, and the garbage collection reclaims the memory for it; this
>   stops the timer and explains why the TimerCallback method is called
>   just once.
>
> Let’s say that you’re using a debugger to step through Main, and a
>   garbage collection just happens to occur just after t is assigned the
>   address of the new Timer object. Then, let’s say that you try to view
>   the object that t refers to by using the debugger’s Quick Watch
>   window. What do you think will happen? **The debugger can’t show you the
>   object because it was just garbage collected**. This behavior would be
>   considered very unexpected and undesirable by most developers, so
>   Microsoft has come up with a solution.
>
> When you compile your assembly using the C# compiler’s /debug switch,
>   the compiler applies a System.Diagnostics.DebuggableAttribute with its
>   DebuggingModes’ DisableOptimizations flag set into the resulting
>   assembly. At run time, when compiling a method, the JIT compiler sees
>   this flag set, and artificially extends the lifetime of all roots to
>   the end of the method. For my example, **the JIT compiler tricks itself
>   into believing that the t variable in Main must live until the end of
>   the method.** So, if a garbage collection were to occur, the garbage
>   collector now thinks that t is still a root and that the Timer object
>   that t refers to will continue to be reachable. The Timer object will
>   survive the collection, and the TimerCallback method will get called
>   repeatedly until Console.ReadLine returns and Main exits.

Comment: Woah, what if he wants to remove the file from disk and we are all assume the variable?   Mind blown.

Comment: @Botonomous then the question is not clear :)

Comment: I cant figure out why someone would ask a question about disposing a local string.. Maybe he comes from c++ land.

Comment: Simply *not using the variable anymore* does the work for you.  No need to null it.

Answer (score 6):

You don't have to worry about your variable `strFile5`, once out of scope it will be collected by the Garbage collector. There is nothing that you have to do.

Also, There is no need to use `Rgex.Replace` a simple `string.Replace` would do the job.

You can also do that all in a single statement without involving any variable like:

```
File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\dennis\Desktop\regex2.txt",
                   File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\dennis\Desktop\regex.txt")
                        .Replace("Documents", "document2"));
```

Comment: To be pedantic, it would be more correct to say "once out of scope it *may* be collected by the Garbage collector *at some point*." Either way, at that point it's no longer the developer's concern unless it contains some sensitive data.

Comment: @GlorinOakenfoot, plus if it contains sensitive data, that is is better to use [`SecureString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: how use secure string  over regex ?

Comment: @zero625, don't worry about `SecureString`, it has nothing to do with Regex and possibly with the scope your question.